# Scrapy - How can I parse information on a per domain level

Tags: python, scrapy

I am fairly new to Scrapy and struggling with coming up with a way to parse information per domain level. So hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Currently I am using the framework to scan a list of our sites for links and then exporting them via the CSV option. This works fine to a certain point but rather than retrieving the individual pages and the corresponding links I would like to group the results on a domain basis.
For example:

```
example.com, [link1,link2,link3,link4]
```

What would be the best way to go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a custom pipeline, http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html.

It'd look something like this:

```
class LinksFromDomain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._spider_to_domains = {}

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self._spider_to_domains[spider] = {}

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # write out a csv file with all the items in some format.
        self._spider_to_domains[spider] = {}

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        domains_dict = self._spider_to_domains[spider]
        if item['domain'] not in domains_dict:
            domains_dict[item['domain']] = []

        domains_dict[item['domain']].extend(item['links'])
```

Comment: Thats great, what would be the best way to make it multidimensional? So example.com: [link1,link2,link3,link4], [other1,other2,other3,other4]

Comment: domains_dict[item['domain']].append(item['links'])

For every item coming in another array is added to the domains dict value. Therefore, you'll get a multi dimensional array in the result.